# Can't save CDocument in a worker thread -- object is destroyed from memory before thread starts

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc

## Overview

I need to save a CDocument in a background worker thread. There is a point in our MFC application which prompts the user to save before continuing. Normally, they are able to continue without saving, and there is no problem. However, occasionally, we need that document later in the process, so if the user clicks "No", we want to save a temp version of the file in the background without making the user wait for the save to continue.

## Problem

When I launch `AfxBeginThread(SaveDocumentThread, &threadInput)` the &threadinput has been cleared from memory before the SaveDocumentThread starts.

## Code

```cpp
BOOL SPackagerDoc::OnSaveDocument( IN LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    ProcessDocumentThreadInput threadInput(this, lpszPathName);
    
    // Temp Save Mode
    if (m_bTempMode)
    {
        m_TempSaveThread = AfxBeginThread(SaveDocumentThread, &threadInput);
        // This fixes the problem, but is considered unstable
        // if (m_TempSaveThread->m_hThread)
        //        WaitForSingleObject(m_TempSaveThread->m_hThread, 500);
        return TRUE;
    }

    // Normal save mode
    SFileLoadingDialog loadingDialog(SFileLoadingDialog::SAVE, lpszPathName, SaveDocumentThread, &threadInput);
    BOOL result = (BOOL)loadingDialog.DoModal();

    return result;
} 

StUInt32 SPackagerDoc::SaveDocumentThread(IN StVoid* pParam)
{
    ProcessDocumentThreadInput* input = (ProcessDocumentThreadInput*)pParam;
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(input);
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(input->pPackager);
    ASSERT_NOT_NULL(input->pszPathName);

    CString path_name(input->pszPathName);

    BOOL result = input->pPackager->SPackagerDocBase::OnSaveDocument(path_name);
    return result;
}
```

If I uncommend `WaitForSingleObject(..., 500);` then the thread starts, all the information is present, and there are no errors. But if I remove those lines then in SaveDocumentThread input is NULL and all data is zeros or garbage.

Is there a way to ensure the SaveDocumentThread has started before moving on. IE, wait for thread to start, but not for a specified amount of time (500 ms). It may be that 500 ms is not a sufficient wait time on some other computers.

Is there an "official" way to do this?

Comment: I don't know MFC, but I know that passing a pointer to a local variable to a separate thread and then returning from the function before the thread has finished execution is a recipe for disaster, because there is no guarantee that whatever that pointer points to still exists by the time your thread runs.

Comment: You passed local variable `threadInput` to another thread. It'll be destroyed before "another thread" starts. Put it in a class member variable should be okay.

Comment: Despite the recommendations appearing to fix the immediate issue, they are all ignoring a more fundamental issue: You cannot safely pass pointers to threads. Once you do, you will have to add synchronization *everywhere*. That, in itself, is already a hard problem to solve, and even experienced software engineers tend to [forget the message queue in the lock hierarchy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110418-00/?p=10913). The "official" way is to never share data accessed by the UI thread with any other thread.

Comment: @IInspectable I assume that `threadInput` is some kind of "snapshot" of the document on it's own. and that `SaveDocumentThread` will only deal with `threadInput` and nothing else. Otherwise your comment is o course correct.

Comment: @jab There's no reason to assume that this *"snapshot"* were not a `CDocument*`, a shallow copy. It's mind-boggling, how we struggle to avoid value semantics in C++. Sean Parent [explained this](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#value-semantics-and-concept-based-polymorphism) almost a decade ago. Juan Pedro Bolivar [reiterated](https://youtu.be/sPhpelUfu8Q) on this a few years back. And still, we're using reference semantics *everywhere* in C++, when we could simply pass values across threads and not have to worry about anything.

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue of the [scope of variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).
Following comments specified the scope of local variable `threadInput`.

```cpp
    ProcessDocumentThreadInput threadInput(this, lpszPathName); // <=== threadInput created
    
    if (m_bTempMode)
    {
        m_TempSaveThread = AfxBeginThread(SaveDocumentThread, &threadInput);
        // This fixes the problem, but is considered unstable
        // if (m_TempSaveThread->m_hThread)
        //        WaitForSingleObject(m_TempSaveThread->m_hThread, 500);
        return TRUE; // <=== threadInput destructed
    }
```

Your workaround `WaitForSingleObject()` delays the destruction of the variable `threadInput` and you see the result.

To overcome the scope of local variable.

1. Store it in a class member variable.
2. Store it as a (*better be smart*) pointer and (*better not to*) handle it's destruction.

Edit:

As @Jabberwocky stated, function `OnSaveDocument()` might be called more than twice since it's called by background thread.

I'll suggest to refactor the `save()` function out and let `if` and `else` to call them seperately.

Comment: The case of reentrancy needs to be handled too: if `OnSaveDocument` is called twice in a row, the thread of the first call might not yet have ended, and thus you might end up with 2 threads saving simultaneously.

Comment: That's a brilliant point I missed. I'll update it later.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the problem is the lifetime of `threadInput` ends before the thread begins.

You can dynamically allocate the instance of `ProcessDocumentThreadInput` and pass the pointer to that instance to the thread.

```cpp
auto* threadInput = new ProcessDocumentThreadInput(this, lpszPathName);
...
AfxBeginThread(SaveDocumentThread, threadInput);
```

However, in this case, the responsibility to release the memory gets messy.
Since you put C++11 tag in your question, you might want to make use of `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` and pass it to the thread, which would land you in using `std::thread` instead of AfxBeginThread. (BTW, I have no experience using MFC.)

```cpp
BOOL SPackagerDoc::OnSaveDocument( IN LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
    ...
    std::thread t(SaveDocumentThread, std::make_unique<ProcessDocumentThreadInput>(this, lpszPathName));
    ...
}

...

StUInt32 SaveDocumentThread(std::unique_ptr<ProcessDocumentThreadInput>&& threadInput)
{
   ...
}
```